# Changing the opacity of the colour on the Polar Area chart

Tags: python, jquery, django, charts, chart.js

I am using Chart.js to create a set of polar area charts, I want to change teh opacity of the colour used to display the data so it is slightly transparent.

Below you will find the code:

```
var totals = {{ class_submission_totals|safe }}
    {% for t in type_qs %}
        var labels_{{ t.pk }} = []
        var backgroundColors_{{ t.pk }} = []
        {% for b in behaviour_qs %}
            {% if b.type.pk == t.pk and not b.previous %}
                labels_{{ t.pk }}.push("{{ b.title }}")
                backgroundColors_{{ t.pk }}.push("{{ b.primarycolour }}")
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  
      
            new Chart("chart_{{ i.pk }}_{{ t.pk }}", {
              type: "polarArea",
              data: {
                labels: labels_{{ t.pk }},
                datasets: [{
                  fillOpacity: 0.3,
                  pointRadius: 1,
                  backgroundColor: backgroundColors_{{ t.pk }},
                  data: totals_{{ i.pk }}_{{ t.pk }}_arr,
                }]
              },
              options: {
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'Chart.js Polar Area Chart'
                    }
                }
              }
            });

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: have you tried passing a rgba() value as backgroundColor?
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp

Comment: Thanks that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp
I altered the values in my django adim and set the primary colours to rgba values and it made them transparent

E.G:
rgba(255,0,0,0.5)